# Nuxt 3, baseUrl and payload.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I have a problem where nuxt 3 is forcing the payload.js to be at root-level. I need it to be with the other assets in the _nuxt folder or in another subfolder.

When I change the baseURL it works, but then it seems the vue router now redirects the index page to the baseURL. So I need to either find a different way to output the payload.js or find a way to change the vue routers base url.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

```
app: {
    baseURL: '/mysubfolder/something',
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your project.

```
    serveStatic: true,
    output: {
      dir: 'mysubfolder/.output',
      serverDir: 'mysubfolder/.output/server',
      publicDir: 'mysubfolder/.output/public'
    }
  }
```